# quero que uma imagem fecha e começa uma contagem regressiva de 5 segundos

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando fazer uma imagem subir ao topo ao clicar nela em baixo. Depois de ter subido quero que ao clicar em ( clique aqui para fechar) quero que comece uma contagem de 5 segundos e depois fechar quando terminar esses 5 segundos. É tipo um anuncio. Veja qui no site:>> https://jsfiddle.net/9hxkL4ba/15/

```js
jQuery.cookie = function(key, value, options) {
  // key and at least value given, set cookie...
  if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
    options = jQuery.extend({}, options);
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      options.expires = -1;
    }
    if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
      var days = options.expires,
        t = options.expires = new Date();
      t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
    }
    value = String(value);
    return (document.cookie = [
      encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
      options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
      options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
      options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
      options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
      options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
    ].join(''));
  }

  // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
  options = value || {};
  var result, decode = options.raw ? function(s) {
    return s;
  } : decodeURIComponent;
  return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1005]) : null;
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($.cookie('popup_facebook_box') != 'yes') {
    $('#fbox-background').delay(5000).fadeIn('medium');
    $('#fbox-button, #fbox-close').click(function() {
      $('#fbox-background').stop().fadeOut('medium');
    });
  }
  $.cookie('popup_facebook_box', 'yes', {
    path: '/',
    expires: 1
  });
});
```

```css
#fbox-display {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/txK4QBP.png);
  border: 0px solid gray;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 237px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 32%;
  left: 35%;
}

.st_font {
  background: #B6000000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

img#fbox-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2147483646;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#fbox-link,
#fbox-link a.visited,
#fbox-link a,
#fbox-link a:hover {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#fbox-background {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='fbox-background'>

  <div id='fbox-display'>
    <img id="fbox-close" src="https://i.imgur.com/TdlMROf.jpg">
    <div class="st_font">

      <div id='fbox-button'></div>
    </div>




  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setInterval` com valor `1000` para gerar o contador em segundos. No primeiro click, o botão "Fechar" irá para o topo da `div`, e no segundo click irá mostrar a `div` do contador e disparar a contagem.

Para isso é preciso criar a `div` onde estará a contagem. Insira no seu CSS os estilos:

```
#aguarde{
   background: #ddd;
   width: 40%;
   height: 40%;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-weight: bold;
   z-index: 999;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-left: -20%;
   margin-top: -16%;
   display: none;
}

#aguarde b{
   position: absolute;
   top: -18px;
   width: 100%;
   background: #fff;
}

#aguarde span{
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

E insira no HTML a `div` da contagem:

```
<div id='fbox-background'>
   <div id='fbox-display'>
      <img id="fbox-close" src="https://i.imgur.com/TdlMROf.jpg">
      <div class="st_font">
         <div id='fbox-button'></div>
      </div>

      <!-- div da contagem -->
      <div id="aguarde">
         <b>ESPERE FECHAR</b>
         <span>5</span>
      </div>
      <!-- div da contagem -->

   </div>
</div>
```

E o JS com os eventos:

```
$('#fbox-button, #fbox-close').click(function() {

   var el = $('#fbox-close');

   if(parseInt(el.css('top')) < 0){

      $('#aguarde').css('display','flex');
      el.hide();

     var contador = 5,
     tempo = setInterval(function(){

        if(contador == 0){
           clearInterval(tempo);
           $('#fbox-close, #fbox-background').hide();
        }else{
           contador--;
           $('#aguarde span').text(contador);
        }
     }, 1000);

   }

   el.css('top','-'+el.height()+'px');

});
```

Veja funcionando no **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hxkL4ba/22/)**

Comment: o que eu queria na verdade era desse jeito aqui como tá na imagem > https://i.imgur.com/TZAHMja.png

Comment: Ok. vou analisar.

Comment: Vc quer que suba e desça?

Comment: Vc quer que a parte de clicar suba, ou seja, o usuário terá que clicar 2 vezes para começar a contagem. É isso?

Comment: é, nao consigo fazer isso

Comment: Alterei a resposta e o Fiddle.

Comment: obg, man.. era assim msm.

Answer (score 0):

> Utilize **setTimeout** do Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($.cookie('popup_facebook_box') != 'yes') {
  $('#fbox-background').delay(5000).fadeIn('medium');
    $('#fbox-button, #fbox-close').click(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('#fbox-background').stop().fadeOut('medium');
      }, 5000);
   });
  }
 $.cookie('popup_facebook_box', 'yes', {
  path: '/',
  expires: 1
 });
});
```

Comment: toh tentando fazer é desse jeito como tá na imagem -> https://i.imgur.com/TZAHMja.png